# How to write a script to add a button to the header of the 3D View?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

I am trying to learn how to script in blender and also the basics of creating addons. Most beginner tutorials show how to make menus in the N panel. But I really want to know how to make menus in the header of the 3D View.

[image]

I tried to write something myself but it doesnt work at all.

```
import bpy
  
class Custom(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label= "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "PT_Custom"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'HEADER'
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
            
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Add an object", icon= 'CUBE')
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon= 'CUBE')
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", icon= 'SPHERE')
        row.operator("object.text_add")  
    

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Custom)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Custom)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   register()
```

Looking forwards to your replies.

Comment: Cloud you refer Text Editor > Templates > **ui_menu.py**. However use *VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus* instead of *INFO_HT_header*.

Comment: Thanks mate this is what I was exactly what i was looking for. You can post this as an answer. Now i gonna try and find out to change the appearance of the menu button